# Is it possible to use a text field as external key (using ActiveRecord)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is it possible to use a string field as external key (using ActiveRecord) ?

Practical example:

I have 2 models:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :kind
end

class Kind < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books
end
```

I **don't** want to use the usual **'kind_id' (integer)** in the book table, but I want to use **'kind_code' (string)**

I've never tried to do that.

- Is it possible ?
- Is it enough to add `:foreign_key => "kind_id"` ?
- What about about the `kind_id` ? (should I remove it ?)

Many thanks
Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt suggest you to do this. If you only want it because of URL rewriting you can also redeclare the `to_param` method in the model like this:

```
def to_param
    "#{id}-#{kind_code}"
end
```

Anyway it is possible to use an alternatvie `foreign_key` like you said but using only `foreign_key`is not enough. You also need to add the `primary_key` parameter like this.

```
belongs_to :kind, :foreign_key => 'kind_code', :foreign_key => 'code'
```

You can find additional examples in the documentation, just search for "foreign_key" => http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html